# Flash UrlLoader - prevent or suppress authentication dialog box

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4

I have a rssfeed application made in `Adobe AIR`. It uses the `UrlLoader` to read the feeds. I need the application to **never** prompt the user to enter password for a website or accept a certificate of a website if is no longer valid. I prefer to have it fail instead.

I have setup the event listeners for IO+Error and Security_ERROR but that is not enough

Sample urls(this may not work in future)

http://www.dawnanddrew.com/rss2.xml  (asks for user and pass atm)

I had another issue with a feed that even if it was a http url the website redirected the loader to https and then the certificate validation failed and the user was asked to accept the certificate. I need this to fail (I mark failed feeds and the user can check them when they want to find the issue and fix them or remove them)

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote - it's a very good question that isn't covered many places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AIR (which you are), you can actually tell the application to NOT handle authentication.

```
var request:URLRequest =new URLRequest("http://www.dawnanddrew.com/rss2.xml");
request.authenticate = false; //default is true, so you need to tell your request to not handle authentication
```

Then it will fail with an IO error instead of prompting for credentials.

[Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#authenticate)

Note however, this will only work in AIR and is not a supported property for flash player.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do it this way. Now, the server returns specific status and the browser reacts to it by showing you a login dialog box. You cannot do this directly in flash and you cannot get default login button. You need to implement this by your own. The perfect way to do so is to check (server side) if the user is logged in and if not - return status ok (200) with an error message (let's say JSON). This specific message would be read by the flash client and a login screen would be shown (custom made). You will also need to implement the login feature by yourself :)

Sorry for the bad news, but this is the way it is with flash.

Comment: I am implementing a rss application, so I do not control the rss feed url or the content at that url, I am wondering why UrlLoader works like a browser instead of working like maybe "wget".  Maybe is the way of how is implemented. Thanks for the response